# Turborepo says npm not installed

Tags: npm, next.js, vercel, monorepo, turborepo

? Which package manager do you want to use?

- npm (not installed)

> pnpm

- yarn (not installed)

? Which package manager do you want to use?

> npm

- pnpm
- yarn (not installed)

Comment: Do you have Node or npm installed on your machine globally? To check simply run these commands "node -v" or "npm -v" in the same terminal where Turborepo says "npm not installed"

Comment: @SimranSingh i have both installed globally but still get this error, i use windows

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the `globalPassThroughEnv` and it works now.

Before i remove `globalPassThrough` :

[image: Before i remove globalPassThrough]

After i remove `globalPassThrough` :
[image: after i remove globalPassThrough]